# How to return an array to use for future script or It block in Protractor method?, Here my intension was to validate array with another array

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

How to return an array to use for future script or It block in Protractor method?, Here my intension was to validate array with another array

```
 it('Verify Non Expired Announcements', function () {
                var  TitlesArray = [];
                // browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
                HomePage.SettingsIcon().click();
                HomePage.SettingsIconSiteContentOption().click();
                NewsAndAnnouncements.SharePointContentSettingAccouncmentSection().click();
                 // below function returns me an array of dates
                NewsAndAnnouncements.getColumnData('Expires').then(function (DateArray) {
                // below function returns me an array of dates which removes past dates 
                    NewsAndAnnouncements.ExtractFutureAndCurrentDate(DateArray).then(function (Dates) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < Dates.length; i++) {
                             {
                              // below function returns me an array of titles associated with below Fuction    
                                 NewsAndAnnouncements.NonExpiredTitles(Dates[i]).getText().then(function (TitleNames)
                         TitlesArray.push(TitleNames);   
                        console.log("Before Function Array : ", TitlesArray);
                            };
                        }

                        console.log("After Function Array : ", TitlesArray);

                });

            });

        });
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring TitlesArray as a public variable (outside IT function)?

Comment: Tried that , I also declared TitlesArray as global variable also but no use.